# How to update child class argument to new value?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have the following code, one parent class and one child class. Two positional arguments will be passed into the parent class and the child class inherits them. Child class contains a method, when it's called, it should change the value of "self.B" from "B = 0" in the parent class to a new value that's after the prompt. How do I update the f-string value of "B" in the "print" statement under "except"? Why is the value of "self.B" unchanged after I typed in a value for it?
'''

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, A: str, B = 0):
        self.A = A 
        self.B = B

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, A: str, B = 0):
        super().__init__(A, B)

    def enter_prompt(self):
        while True:
           try:
               self.B = float(input('Please enter a numerical value: ')
           except ValueError:
               print(f"Item A {self.A}'s new value B {self.B} must be a numerical value, please try again!")
           else:
               break
        print(f"Item A {self.A}'s new value is {self.B}.")
        return self.A, self.B
```

## After I run the following:

'''

```
P = Parent('Alpha', 0)
C = Child(P.A, P.B)
C.enter_prompt()
```

'''

## My terminal:

```
Please enter a numerical value: www
Item A Alpha's new value B 0 is not a new numerical value, please try again!
Please enter a numerical value: 15.5
Item A Alpha's new value is 15.5.
```

'''
I thought the value of self.B would be changed to whatever value I typed in and be printed out in the string. Not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That input "www" isn't accepted?

Comment: No, the problem is the www isn't updated to self. B and is printed out. self.B still had its initial value from the __init__ in the parent class.

Comment: I want the "B 0" in this string "Item A Alpha's new value B 0 is not a new numerical value, please try again!" to update to "Item A Alpha's new value B www is not a new numerical value, please try again!"

Comment: Why are you creating separate instances of `Parent` and `Child`? `C = Child('Alpha', 0)`. I have no idea what, exactly, `enter_prompt` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: the enter_prompt function is suppose to update the value of self.B. I need this to work so any user can change its value.

Comment: First assign the result of `input` to a new variable (which you can use in the error message). Then try to convert this variable to `float` and assign the result to `self.B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion has to do with *when* the `ValueError` exception gets raised. You seem to expect the assignment to happen first, then the exception to stop further progress. But that's not how it works. In:

```
self.B = float(input('Please enter a numerical value: ')
```

The exception comes from the `float` call, which needs to be evaluated before any assignment happens (since it's the *result* of that call that is assigned). When the value from `input` is invalid in `float`, no assignment happens at all.

If you want to be able to print out the invalid user input, do a separate assignment for that, before you convert it to a float:

```
b_str = input('Please enter a numerical value: ')
try:
    self.B = float(b_str)
except:
    print(f"Item A {self.A}'s new value B {b_str} must be a numerical value, please try again!")
else:
    break
```

Note that you might want to print out the `repr` of the value, rather than the value directly (so you'll get quotation marks and special characters will be escaped), though it might not be necessary in this specific situation (since the user had to type the value for you to get it via `input()`). You can have an f-string format a value using `repr` by putting `!r` after the expression in the curly brackets:

```
print(f"Item A {self.A}'s new value B {b_str!r} must be a numerical value, please try again!")
```